# interface{}型で受け取った引数を元の型に戻してjson.Unmarshalしたい

Tags: go

実現したいことは、json.Unmarshalを単純にラップした関数の作成なのですが、Unmarshalに渡す構造体はinterface{}型の引数として受け取りたいです。
　しかし以下のように実現できていません。どのような方法があるでしょうか。

**ステップ１：ベースとなるコード**

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {

    j := []byte(`{"name": "ando"}`)

    var user User
    if err := json.Unmarshal(j, &user); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", user)
    //=> main.User{Name:"ando"}
}
```

**ステップ２：interface{}型をそのまま渡して失敗**

json.Unmarshalをラップした、unmarshal関数を作成。しかし、interface{}型をそのままUnmarshalに渡してしまったので、map型で返ってきてしまった。

```golang
func main() {

    bs := []byte(`{"name": "ando"}`)

    var user User

    _, err := unmarshal(bs, user)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

func unmarshal(bs []byte, st interface{}) (interface{}, error) {

    if err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &st); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", st)
    //=> map[string]interface {}{"name":"ando"}

    return st, nil
}
```

**ステップ３：reflectパッケージで元の構造体に復元したつもりが失敗**

初めてreflectパッケージを使い、見よう見まねでinterface{}型から元の構造体を復元したつもりが、エラーにはならないが正常にデコードされない。

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func unmarshal(bs []byte, st interface{}) (interface{}, error) {

    // 元の構造体を復元しようとしたつもり
    rv := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(st)).Elem()

    if err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &rv); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", rv)
    //=> main.User{Name:""} ※値が初期値のまま

    return rv, nil
}
```

Comment: ステップ3の場合、`json.Unmarshal()` の第2引数は `interface{}`型なので、`rv := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(st)).Interface()` として、`json.Unmarshal(bs, rv)` とするのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

自己回答です。（metropolisさんのコメントから）

まだしっかりと理解できてないのですが、以下で実現できましたのでとりあえず回答として残します。

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    bs := []byte(`{"name": "ando"}`)

    u, err := unmarshal(bs, User{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    user := u.(User)
    fmt.Printf("%s", user.Name)
    //=> ando
}

func unmarshal(bs []byte, st interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    rv := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(st)).Interface()
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &rv); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return reflect.ValueOf(rv).Elem().Interface(), nil
}
```